# send sms from background

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager

```
 1)  Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + phoneNumber);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
                    intent.putExtra("sms_body", smsBody);

                    startActivity(intent);
```

this is code for sending sms. but action_SENDTO does not send sms directly to other user. action_sendto just shows sms box fill with other user name and smsbody.

how could sms send directly to other user with sms body ?

```
2) SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
   smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, smsBody , null, null);
```

this is another code also not working...

Comment: "how could sms send directly to other user with sms body ?" -- use `SmsManager`. "also not working" -- this is not a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), let alone an actual explanation of what "not working" means.

Comment: not working means.. nothing happened. ..if you send sms using native method or using smsmanager then there must be main balance(talk time balance) deducted by 10 bugs or 1 rupee like that. but when i execute this code nothing going to happened.

Comment: SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:    this error is shown when execute with Smsmanager.

Answer (score 0):

add send sms permission to your manifest

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />  already added...............SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE: shown in console

Answer (score 0):

Add this this in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

You app must be have rights to send sms messages

Answer (score 0):

first go to AndroidManifest file and add the below code

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />`

after that goto mainactivity copy the below function

```
private void sendLongSMS(String messag) {

    String phoneNumber = "+countrycode_mobilenumber"; // like this +911234567890
    String message = messag; // up to 160 characters 

    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    ArrayList<String> parts = smsManager.divideMessage(message);
    smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, null, null);
}
```

after that call the above function  inside oncreate thats it.

please test this code in real devices  it will work.